# jQuery Uploader uploading time from server

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-file-upload, jquery-upload-file-plugin

I am using jQuery Uploader on Codeigniter, and it works very fine in localhost.

In the real server, if I upload big files like video then the progress bar reaches on 100%, but still need more time to finish uploading.

What I can guess from there is, it needs a time to save the file to server and the progress bar only shows the progress of uploading time from client side.

Would you give me some idea how to solve this?

---

I have found Waiting (TTFB) takes time to complete the process. What I can guess from here is, writing the file on server takes time. Still no idea how to solve this

Comment: Are you moving file on server after upload? Have you check enough rights on directory? What are php configuration you have update?

Comment: Just uploading a video file from local to server. There is a enough rights on directory and done a configuration on php.ini for file max size. I am not moving the file after uploading, just uploading only. but the progress bar stays on 100% and does not complete the process for a while.

Comment: After loader hits 100% than put in "Saving the video", until everything is done.